# Having problems with LaTeX coding in Rmarkdown (fancyhdr, \headheight)

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, r

I'm currently having an issue with latex in Rmarkdown (using fancyhdr package). I am trying to make a data report with a certain template style. This is a screenshot of the pdf at its current stage and as you can see the title "Equity1" (entire page body) is higher up than in the page 2.

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

These are the codes on my YAML of Rmarkdown

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
header-includes:|
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \newcommand{\helv}{%
    \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.png}}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{Daily Report}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf\selectfont\sffamily{NOT INTENDED FOR FORWARDING}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
classoption: a4paper
---
```

And these are in the rest of the codes:

````
> ## \selectfont\sffamily{EQUITY 1}
> 
> ```{r}
> # content page 1 
> ```  
> \newpage

> ## \selectfont\sffamily{EQUITY 2} 
> ```{r}
> # content page 2 
> ```
````

I was wondering if I made a mistake in my YAML or in my code later on? (I am using LateX through rMarkdown because I am trying to have it available as a PDF for my output).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will get a warning in the log file about the headheight. Read the warning and act accordingly.

Comment: @Johannes_B when you mean act according, I was wondering how to code it in Tex. The error code says: Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 32.08571pt. How should I go by creating a headheight of 32pt?

Comment: I'm chiming in a bit late, but the command is `\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}`, to be placed before `\begin{document}`. If you round the number it should be rounded up, not down. The latest version of `fancyhdr` will tell you this command.